# writing a function to $_POST using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to create a function so I can send $_POST using ajax.
I made code like this but it is not working.

```
function send(variable, value){
      var e = value;
      bar = variable;
      $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "vote.php",
            data: {bar:e},
            success:function(){
            console.log(e);
            }
        });
  }
```

I can see the problem is that data{bar} is not getting the variable value.
How can I make it so that I can get `$_POST['dog'] = corgi` when I write the function

```
send(dog, corgi)
```

and `$_POST['cat'] = bengal` when I write

```
send(cat, bengal)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects created like this do not interpret variables as property names, so `bar` as the property of an object is literally `"bar"`. You need to create an object, and dynamically set properties using the variable in bracket notation.

## Example:

```
function send(variable, value){
      var e = value;
      var data = {};
      data[variable] = value;
      $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "vote.php",
            data: data,
            success:function(){
            console.log(e);
            }
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Upvoted Alexander's answer - think he's technically spot on.

Two observations: in your example you state you want to use

```
send(cat, bengal)
```

Obv you either need variables called ***cat*** and ***bengal*** tho suspect you actaully want to use

```
send('cat', 'bengal')
```

Probably just a typeo / oversight in your original question...?

As an aside (I realise this doesn't directly answer OP), a more deterministic approach and closer to JS good practices would be to use $.extend and hand an "options" object in:

```
send({cat : "bengal"})
```

and internally use:

```
function send(options){
  var defaultData = {}; // your defaults here (can be closured off somewhere else other than here if you need to)

  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "vote.php",
        data: $.extend({}, defaultData, options || {}) // handle when you dont hand in options with the '|| {}' bit
    });
```

}

HTH

Comment: Excellent!  Delighted to help.